# Replace missing values at once in both categorical and numerical columns

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to replace NAN values in both categorical columns as well as numerical columns at once?

A very simplistic example:

```
data = {'col_1': [3, np.nan, 1, 2], 'col_2': ['a', 'a', np.nan, 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Dataframe:

```
    col_1   col_2
0   3.0     a
1   NaN     a
2   1.0    NaN
3   0.0     d
```

Goal:

To replace `col_1`'s NAN with the `mean` of `col_1` and replace `col_2`'s NAN with the `mode ('a')` of `col_2`.

Right now, I have to replace it for each column individually. If all columns are numeric or categorical then it's easy because the operation can be applied on the whole data frame but I couldn't find a way to do it one line for a mixed data frame.

Comment: is `col2` just `object` or `category` dtype?

Comment: @ALollz In my actual dataset, its `category` dtype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mean` will only work for numeric types, so fill that first then fill the remainder with mode.

```
df.fillna(df.mean()).fillna(df.mode().iloc[0])

#   col_1 col_2
#0    3.0     a
#1    2.0     a
#2    1.0     a
#3    2.0     d
```

If you have ties, the mode will be the one that is sorted first.

Comment: I tried it another a different dataset where categorical columns have a type object and it didn't work on the categorical columns with type object. Do you have any idea why this happened? For now, I have changed the object type to category and then it works.

Comment: I tried it again to recreate the problem and it works now even with dtype object. I might have messed up something in my notebook earlier.

Answer (score 1):

What I will do

```
df.fillna(df.agg(['mean',lambda x : x.value_counts().index[0]]).ffill().iloc[-1,:])
   col_1 col_2
0    3.0     a
1    2.0     a
2    1.0     a
3    2.0     d
```